# Does elasticsearch's _id field support blank char like "" when use bulkrequest to write data to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently, when I write data into elasticsearch with BulkRequest, I got the following exception:

```java
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation Failed: 1: id is missing;
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequest.validate(BulkRequest.java:614)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1731)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1697)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.bulk(RestHighLevelClient.java:473)
    at com.clougence.cloudcanal.es6.task.write.full.Es6FullInsertExecutorImpl.insert(Es6FullInsertExecutorImpl.java:70)
    at com.clougence.cloudcanal.es6.task.write.full.Es6FullApplyHandler.handle(Es6FullApplyHandler.java:35)
    at com.clougence.cloudcanal.es6.task.write.full.Es6FullApplyHandler.handle(Es6FullApplyHandler.java:16)
    at com.clougence.cloudcanal.task.applier.full.FullApplyWorkHandler.onEvent(FullApplyWorkHandler.java:61)
    at com.clougence.cloudcanal.task.applier.full.FullApplyWorkHandler.onEvent(FullApplyWorkHandler.java:20)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.WorkProcessor.run(WorkProcessor.java:143)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My code is as follows. I debug my code and find the esIdValue is blank and this cause the exception.

```java
    updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().index(indexDef.getIndexName())
                    .id(esIdValue)
                    .type(DEFAULT_TYPE)
                    .doc(docMap)
                    .docAsUpsert(true);
                bulkRequest.add(updateRequest);
```

My question is does elasticsearch support write a doc with _id value "". Can I put the empty _id value into es?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES _id field doesn't support blank char like "".

You have 2 options:

- Always provide an id
- You just need to remove the id field that you have and elastic will assign an auto-generated one in "_id" field.
  Something like

  ```
     updateRequest = new UpdateRequest().index(indexDef.getIndexName())                    
              .type(DEFAULT_TYPE)
              .doc(docMap)
              .docAsUpsert(true);
          bulkRequest.add(updateRequest)
  ```